# About Null character in C language

Tags: c, string, character, sizeof, chararray

This is my program:
[Click link to see the program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0JW7d.jpg)
In this program,

```
char c[5] = "hello\0world";
```

When I print the string `c` using the following line:

```
printf("\nstring c=%s", c);
```

It gives the following output (with smile symbol at the end, not exactly like the symbol below, but I can say it is a smiley symbol:

```
string c=hello(•‿•)
```

Why doesn't it print **hello**
In the output? because the size of string is only 5?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Turn up your compiler warnings! https://wandbox.org/permlink/IvhCo80mCsVRXytW

Answer (score 2):

The array `c` is only 5 characters wide, and the initializer given has too many characters for an array that size.  So only the first 5 characters of the string constant are used to initialize the array.

This means that the array contains only the characters `'h'`, `'e'`, `'l'`, `'l'`, and `'o'`.  In other words, you don't have a string because it's not null terminated.  So `printf` ends up reading past the end of the array triggering [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

If you omit the array size:

```
char c[]="hello\0world";
```

It will be made large enough to fit the entire initializer.  Then `printf` will print "hello" since it will stop reading at the null byte.

Comment: I have a question.here the size of char c is 5. So should it not store only four characters i.e."hell" and  a null character "\0" at the end?

Comment: @Heli_Aghara No, because that's not what it's being initialized with.  A `char` array doesn't necessarily have to hold a null-terminated string.

Comment: So, if we don't add a Null character in this case i.e. char c[5]="hello\0world" ,it is not a string bt just a character array.right?

Comment: @Heli_Aghara Yes, the null terminator is what makes it a string.